# Dynamic Index Creation in ElasticSearch-Spark Framework

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark

In my use case, my JSON contains a field "time" which contains value in Unix time. And I want to partition my indexes by this field. That is, if JSON1 contains 1422904680 in "time" and JSON2 contains 1422991080 in time, then I want to create indexes which are partitioned by time (24 hours) like

index_1422835200_1422921599 - which will contain JSON1 because value of "time" = 1422904680 falls in its range.
index_1422921600_1423007999 - which will contain JSON2 because value of "time" = 1422991080 falls in its range.

Now I want to create my indexes dynamically. There is also possibility of receiving a JSON which contain a value of time before current date.

To achieve this, I need to create index name dynamically by calculating it at the time of insertion then and there itself.

Example -

JavaRDD contains JSONs. If one JSON has "time" = t1, then while inserting this JSON, it must be checked that whether index_(t1 - (t1 % 86400))_(t1 + 86400 - (t1 % 86400)) exists or not. If it exists, insert JSON in it, else create it with above name (by calculating) and then insert it.

Programmatically, I want to achieve something like this

```
JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(jrd, "index_{time} - {time} % 86400}_{ {time} + 86400 - {time} % 86400 }/type");
```

where jrd is my JavaRDD containg JSONs.

Is it possible to achieve dynamic index name creation as described above? If no, is there any work around to achieve my use case.

Comment: Hi has it been resolved ? if so could you pls post the solutions as answer to above question?